# Chernoff-type Bounds for Continuous-space Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, inequalities, ergodic-theory, markov-chains, measure-concentration

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be $n$ samples from a discrete-time *continuous-space* Markov Chain.

Are there any good references who have provided a Chernoff-type bound regarding the behaviour of the ergodic mean $\bar X = \frac 1 n \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ for this type of chain?

There is a good line of work about finite-state chains (e.g. [http://www.columbia.edu/~khl2114/files/CLLM.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ekhl2114/files/CLLM.pdf), https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.04467) but I cannot find any work related to continuous-space (i.e. infinite-space) Markov Chains.

Comment: The contraction-based results continue to hold for continuous state spaces (though the Doeblin contraction condition is rather strong):
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610427

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! My hunch was similar but I wanted to see it formalized somewhere.